# Error when debugging flutter project in android studio with Memu play emulator

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I'm new in android studio and I'm trying to run and debug demo flutter project in android studio with Memu play emulator but I have the following error.please help me.

```
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install D:\sample\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERIFICATION_FAILURE]
Error launching application on ASUS Z01QD.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it:

1. go to Memu system setting >> turn root mode on >> press ok and restart
2. go to android setting in Memu >> about tablet >> keep clicking Build number until it shows that you are now a developer
3. go back to android setting >> developer option >> turn USB debugging on

Answer (score 0):

Go to the setting of the emulator and look for an option that allows you to install from unknown sources. Most probably you need to go to the `developer options` and then disable the `verify apps over USB cable` or you need to go to the `privacy` or `security` and `enable Unknown sources`.

Comment: Unfortunately it was not resolved.